# Searching Parse using pointer returns error "pointer field needs a pointer value"

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to do a query by selectedBook (this is a string of selectedBook's objectID). However, I'm getting this error: "[Error]: pointer field book needs a pointer value (Code: 102, Version: 1.8.2)." I believe I have to do the query with the actual book object rather than the objectID, how can I go about doing this? Thanks in advance!!

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"UserTags")
      query.whereKey("book", equalTo:selectedBook)

      query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

         if error == nil {

            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) tags.")

            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

               for object in objects {

                  print(object.objectId)
               }
            }

         } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!)")
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Here is the code in case someone else runs into this:

```
let pointer = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName:"Book", objectId: booksObjectID)

var query = PFQuery(className: "UserTags")

query.whereKey("book", equalTo: pointer)

query.includeKey("book")

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    for object in objects! {

       self.userTags.addObject(object)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/T_Parse_ParseException_ErrorCode.htm):

> **InvalidQuery** - **102** - Error code indicating you tried to query with a
>   datatype that doesn't support it, like exact matching an array or
>   object.

The error description tells you a lot. This kind of querying does not support queuing by object (in your case, book). You have to use a datatype that is supported - for example query by book ID or name which are more primitive data types.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I'm with you about the query needing a different data type. In my example, selectedBook is a string of the book objectID. What should I use instead of this objectID to be able to search for the tags just for this book? Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: And what is the datatype of the key "book"? Isn't it an object?

Comment: "book" is a column in my userTags class that holds a pointer to the book object. The user selects a specific book in prior view controller. I am then trying to pass this book objectID in to query the user tags for only that selected book. I just am unclear what I need to put in `query.whereKey("book", equalTo:selectedBook)` to get it to pull the tags for the book. Thank you!!

Comment: I think the fact that you're passing an object via "book" is the source of problem. Try passing ID of this object there.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. So you're saying to change the column in Parse to be just a string of that book object ID rather than being a pointer to the object itself? Sorry, I'm just trying to get my head wrapped around this.